# Format date in where query of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to know that is there any way to format the date in where query for particular column.
I have a mongo record which has one column called start_date which is stored in string like this: "`20221104`". I need this `start_date` to be formatted like  `"2022-11-04"` in where query.

One way I know is to iterate over the query result and format the date. I'm looking if there is any  other way to achieve this.

```
result = Subscription.where(state: "active")
```

Comment: Why do you need the date formatted in the where clause?  You know the format it is stored in -- why not use the known format for the query?

Comment: It's a little confusing with the two mentioned date formats.  Are you wanting to see a format of "2022-11-04" out of the query results after complete?  But need to start with the format "20221104" because that's the DB format?  Or vice-versa you have the data in "2022-11-04" and need to convert it to the non-dashed variant?

Comment: Date stored in DB is in format: "20221104". Want to see a format of "2022-11-04" out of the query results after complete.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can compare "start_date" to string representation of an input date object in where query.

```
result = Subscription.where(start_date: date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

You can visit [here](https://entrision.com/blog/formatting-dates-in-ruby/) for more details.

Comment: Please share the result that it works or not, thanks!